# Android Launcher3 - Google Now Page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-launcher

I downloaded Launcher3 (Google's Kitkat Launcher) from 4.4 Sources.

I imported it into eclipse . I got rid of errors.And my launcher works pretty good.

But something missing. "GOOGLE NOW" page when you scroll to left.

I can't activate google now.Anyway i don't need that. I want to put my own fragment or layout into first page and other pages will work same like normal launcher. 
Like a Google's experience Launcher(Kitkat Launcher of google)'s Google Now page ..

Like this :
[image]

I added my layout like this :

here is original codes from workspace.java

```
  public long insertNewWorkspaceScreen(long screenId, int insertIndex) {
    if (mWorkspaceScreens.containsKey(screenId)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Screen id " + screenId + " already exists!");
    }

    CellLayout newScreen = (CellLayout)
            mLauncher.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.workspace_screen, null);

    newScreen.setOnLongClickListener(mLongClickListener);
    newScreen.setOnClickListener(mLauncher);
    newScreen.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
    mWorkspaceScreens.put(screenId, newScreen);
    mScreenOrder.add(insertIndex, screenId);
    addView(newScreen, insertIndex);
    return screenId;
}
```

here is edited codes by me on workspace.java

```
      public long insertNewWorkspaceScreen(long screenId, int insertIndex) {
        if (mWorkspaceScreens.containsKey(screenId)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Screen id " + screenId + " already exists!");
        }
if (screenId == 2) //Firstscreen/page
{

 RelativeLayout newScreen = (RelativeLayout)
                mLauncher.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.blinkfeed, null);

        newScreen.setOnClickListener(mLongClickListener);
        newScreen.setOnClickListener(mLauncher);
        newScreen.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
     //   mWorkspaceScreens.put(screenId, newScreen);
        mScreenOrder.add(insertIndex, screenId);
        addView(newScreen, insertIndex);
        return screenId;

}
else
{
        CellLayout newScreen = (CellLayout)
                mLauncher.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.workspace_screen, null);

        newScreen.setOnLongClickListener(mLongClickListener);
        newScreen.setOnClickListener(mLauncher);
        newScreen.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
        mWorkspaceScreens.put(screenId, newScreen);
        mScreenOrder.add(insertIndex, screenId);
        addView(newScreen, insertIndex);
        return screenId;
}
    }
```

as you can see when its first page i changed layout but i'm getting problems on childviews, animations etc,
anyway i cant even access other pages after that.
i putted everywhere try catch when i get errors because of "celllayout cannot bind to relative bla bla .."

my try catch like this

```
try
{
cell layout stuff its trying to make animations etc.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//empty
}
```

i couldn't make it work at the moment like a google now pages :)
does anybody know about adding a fragment/layout into first page ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some fragment or view in the same manner as Google Now, the Launcher3 code supports that. You basically have 2 ways of getting the desired behavior:

- Subclass the Launcher class and overwrite `hasCustomContentToLeft()` to return true and `addCustomContentToLeft()` where you can create/inflate your view to be added. Make sure you call `addToCustomContentPage` and implement the `CustomContentCallbacks` if you want to be notified when the screen is open.
- Implement the same methods as described above in the Launcher class directly.

Hope this helps,
Mihai

Comment: i found that already. about 3 months ago. and my app is on playstore as Do Launcher.. Thanks anyway

Comment: No problem. I am also doing some modifications to the AOSP launcher and while searching for other issues, I found your question. Thought I would add an answer.

Comment: hi can you please explain to me how to add shortcut from all apps to workspace in Launcher3?, here my question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410875/drag-and-drop-icons-to-home-screen

Comment: HI , can we use AOSP's Launcher3 code  , modify it accordingly and upload in playstore ???

Comment: @pradeep.k As far as I know, Launcher3, being part of AOSP is falling under the terms of the Apache License 2.0. You should consult the terms of the license, and see under which conditions you can do what.

Comment: @r1k0 Thank you .I will check it out :)

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple pages to the left? Or add pages to the right?

Comment: @r1k0 can we add view in right side of home screen like above in left side?

Comment: I haven't worked on that code for a while now so I don't know how this can be done. My guess is that it probably can be done but would require some greater amount of work.